# Make avaible x64 C++ exceptions on manually mapped module

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to bind Lua on manually mapped module. As you can see clearly on [here](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/ldo.c#L58).

They are using C++ or C exceptions on their API and there is no way to avoid them.
I wonder to know if there are possibilities to enable that exceptions on my module.

I had tried to patch these line as following:

```
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) c->throwed = true
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) \
    __try { a } except(0xDEADBEEF) { if ((c)->status == 0 && ((c)->throwed == true)) (c)->status = -1; }
#define luai_jmpbuf     int  /* dummy variable */

/* chain list of long jump buffers */
struct lua_longjmp {
  struct lua_longjmp *previous;
  luai_jmpbuf b;
  volatile int status;  /* error code */
  bool throwed;
};
```

And compiled my module with /EHa, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by “manually mapped”? I think we need more details about your environment and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky writing shellcode to victim process and calling it by creating remote thread on usermode without syscalls.